# Can't Store User Information to FireBase Database After Authentication Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is My SignUp Activity. When the Button is pressed it Signs Up the user but does not Store its data in the database. It shows the user signed up in the authentication tab in firebase console but there is no data in the database. This is my SignUp Activity for the Application.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)

    val signin_btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signin_link_btn)
    val signup_btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup_btn)

    signin_btn.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    }

    signup_btn.setOnClickListener{
        createAccount()
    }
}

private fun createAccount() {
    val fullName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.fullname_signup).text.toString()
    val userName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_signup).text.toString()
    val email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email_signup).text.toString()
    val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password_signup).text.toString()

    when {

        TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Full Name is Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) -> Toast.makeText(this, "UserName is Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        TextUtils.isEmpty(email) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Email is Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        TextUtils.isEmpty(password) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Password is Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


    else -> {


        val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{
            task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful)
            {
                saveUserInfo(fullName, userName, email)
            }
            else
                {
            val message = task.exception!!.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            mAuth.signOut()

                }
            }
        }

    }
}

private fun saveUserInfo(fullName: String, userName: String, email: String) {

    val currentUserID= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val usersRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

    val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    userMap["uid"] = currentUserID
    userMap["fullname"] = currentUserID
    userMap["username"] = currentUserID
    userMap["email"] = currentUserID
    userMap["bio"] = "Hey I am using Instagram Clone App."
    userMap["image"] = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-clone-565fe.appspot.com/o/Instagram%20Clonde%20Default%20Images%2Fprofile.png?alt=media&token=494e98e8-8e7d-40ea-8102-97849ac546b7"

    usersRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener {

            task ->
        if(task.isSuccessful){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Account has been created Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
    }
        else
    {
        val message = task.exception!!.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
    }
    }
}
}
```

Rules for my Data base are

```
{  
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  // 2021-8-5
    ".write": "true ",  // 2021-8-5   
  } 
}
```

Here are the gradle dependencies of the project

dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}

Comment: Do you get any errors in the logcat?

Comment: It's worth checking in the firebase console to enabling sign-in services(?) https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/where-to-start

Comment: this error only occurs when typing the credentials for sign up.                                     
07-10 21:12:59.138 20091-20091/com.example.instagramclone E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the Task is not successful? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Can you specify where u want me to use if the task is not successful command. if you are suggesting it in the usersref on complete listener there is an else statement there and it does nothing, also there is no "if not successful command"

Comment: Yes, in the else part, you should try to Log task.getException().getMessage(). Do you get something there?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have typed "else(task.getException()!!.message)" , "else(task.getException()?.message)" and else(task.exception!!.message) still did'nt got anything.

Comment: @Dharmaraj can someone pls answer this??